# best practice dir for rails app on redhat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redhat

I'm installing a Ruby on Rails app on RedHat, using cPanel. What directory would be considered "best practice" for installing the app itself?

Clearly I don't want to use \home\peter\public_html and it looks like \home\peter\ruby was created by default when I ran the \scripts\installruby script.

\home\peter\rubyapps ?
\home\peter\ruby\apps ?
\home\peter\public_rails_apps ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, apps are hosted on:

var/www/yoursite.com

But it's a matter of choice :)

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. Had to create the www directory in the end, but such is life.